# Avoiding object slicing within abstractions and their derivations

Tags: c++, vectors

I've created a rudimentary example of the issue I'm inquiring about: Object slicing. I followed a post on Stack Overflow which provided a similar template - and for all intents and purposes, this works. I was just wondering if this would get me into a trouble longer down the line? Is there anything here that jumps out at you as dangerous and/or wrong?

The heart of the logic is in `main()`. I'm pushing a `Circle` object into a `Shapes*` vector, then push the new `Shapes*` element into a `Circle` vector. The issue I had WITHOUT the assignment operators, was that the compiler couldn't decide how to convert `Shape*` to `Circle`.

Please let me know if there are any glaringly obvious improvements.

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual Shape& operator=(const Shape& s) {
        assign(s);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
    virtual         int getEdges() = 0;



protected:
    std::string name;
    int         edges;

    void assign(const Shape& s) {
        this->name = s.name;
        this->edges = s.edges;
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
private:
    int radius;
public:
    Circle() { name = "Circle"; edges = 1; }
    Circle(int rad) { name = "Circle"; edges = 1; radius = rad; }

    virtual Circle& operator=(const Shape& s) {
        if (const Circle* c = dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&s))
            assign(*c);
        else{
            std::cout << "BAD ASSIGNMENT IN CIRCLE.";
                    //THROW ERROR HERE INSTEAD OF THE ABOVE COUT
            }
        return *this;
    }

    std::string getName() { return name; }
            int getEdges() { return edges; }
            int getRadius() { return radius; }
           void setRadius(int r) { radius = r; }

protected:
    void assign(const Circle& c) {
        Shape::assign(c);
        this->radius = c.radius;
    }

};

int main() {
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
    std::vector<Circle> circs;
    Circle c2(5); //Creates a circle with 5 for the radius.

    shapes.push_back(&c2); //Pushing the 5-radius circle into the Shapes* vector
    Circle c3; //Creates a circle with default constructor (which does NOT define radius)
    c3 = *shapes[0]; //Now, the overloaded assignment operator. Look at Circle::assign(const Shape&) function
    circs.push_back(c3); //We push our newly assigned circle to our Circle vector
    std::cout << "c3 radius: " << circs[0].getRadius(); //This will be 5!
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Allowing a `Shape` to be assigned to a circle does not sound like it is very safe. I suppose there are situations where it can be used but I would advice against it in the general case

Also I would use [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to get around having to write the assignment operator-er in every derived class.

```
class Shape
{ // STUFF
};

template<typename T>
class ShapeCopyable: public Shape
{
    T& operator=(const Shape& s)
    {
        T const& c = dynamic_cast<T const&>(s);  // Throws on bad cast.
        assign(c);

        return *this;
    }
};
class Circle: public ShapeCopyable<Circle>
{
    // Stuff
};
```

In addition to what @Chris Jester-Young covered (so everything he said):

The Base class of a hierarchy with virtual methods should also have a virtual destructor. Otherwise you are going to start having issues with memory management when you start dynamically creating objects on the fly.

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}
```

Don't define the copy constructor or assignment operator if nothing special needs to be done. Let the compiler generated version do the work for you. Unless you have something special in the destructor or have RAW pointer members this is unlikely. PS you should not have RAW pointer members either.

```
    // Remove this:
    virtual Shape& operator=(const Shape& s);
```

Don't like getters/setters. They break encapsulation and expose the internal implementation of the object. You should consider why you need to pass the state of the object out (is the function that uses the values really a member function).

Interactions on the object should usually be done internally to the object. This will get rid of most of your needs for getters and setters. If you still have a need after the analysis fine.

```
    // Don't like them.
    // Make but sometimes you need them but minimze your
    // exposure by using methods that manipulate the object rather
    // than moving the manipulation to an external actor.
    std::string getName() { return name; }
            int getEdges() { return edges; }
            int getRadius() { return radius; }
           void setRadius(int r) { radius = r; }
```

A vector of pointers. Red flag who owns the pointers.

```
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
```

A'hh you are pushing stack objects onto the vector.

```
    shapes.push_back(&c2);
```

Maybe it should be a vector of reference wrapper to Shape `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Shape>>`.

Getting a circle from a shape.

```
    c3 = *shapes[0];
```

Not sure that should really happen. The interface to `Shape` should be how you manipulate the object. Needing to convert the object to a circle seems unnecessary in most situations (you should probably have virtual functions that do the actions you need). Sometimes things have unique actions then you need to convert them back.But in these situations just use dynamic_cast directly (this also shows you are doing the conversion very explicitly).

#### Based on comments below:

> I will need to pull name's and description's to display to the user

Its easier to ask the object to display itself rather the pull details about the object and then display them.

The simplist example is just printing information to a stream:

```
// Original Way
Circle    c(5);
std::cout << "Circle: "  << c.getName() 
          << " Edges: "  << c. getEdges 
          << " Radius: " << c.getRadius()
          << "\n";

// What I would do is make the serialization of the object to a stream
// a member method that does the work.

class Shape
{
    virtual void print(std::ostream& stream) const = 0; // Can print a Shape
                                                  // Must be specialized for 
                                                  // Specific types.

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Shape const& shape)
    {
        shape.print(stream);
        return stream;
    }
};

// Now you print like this:
Circle    c(5);
std::cout << c << "\n";
```

You don't need to expose the members just because you need serialization. Doing it this ways adds consistency so that all objects of a particular type are serialized in the same way. If you need to change what it looks like you have a single place in the code that needs modifying.

We can extend the above to other graphical representations.

```
struct DisplayInterface
{
     // This is an interface for drawing shapes on a display.
     // You can imagine it has the standard drawing functions.
     // But imagine a base set.
     void drawLine(Pt const& tr, Pt const& bl);
     void drawCircle(Pt const& tr center, unsigned int radius);
     void drawPolygon(std::vector<Pt> const& pts);
     void drawText(Pt const& bl, unsigned int fontSize, std::string const& str);
};

// Now in your drawing code you pass the DisplayInterface to the object
// So it can draw itself. So usually the drawing system provides an
// interface that all drawable objects need to implement.

struct Drawable
{
    virtual void display(DisplayInterface& di) = 0;
};

class Shape: public Drawable  // All shapes are drawable
{                             // But each shape must implement
                              // Its own display()
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
     virtual void display(DisplayInterface& di)
     {
          di.drawCircle(Pt(0,0), radius);
          di.drawText(Pt(0,15), 12, name);
     }
};
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but thank you very much for the informative and thorough response.

I'm not sure I like the implementation either, but here's my reasoning (in line with the `Shape` analogy):
My project doesn't contain just `Circle`'s, but a plethora of other shapes (`Triangle`'s, `Square`'s, etc). The user will be in control of X number of `ShapeFactory`'s, which construct `Circle`'s, and other classes derived from `Shape`. Each `Shape` has a different construction length.

Comment: Construction length is in turns (as it is a turn-based game). So, instead of having `vector`'s for `Circle`'s, and all the different derivations to keep track of construction, I push all the derived shapes into a `vector<Shape*>`, and every turn, I simply cycle through the vector and decrement everything that still has turns remaining for construction. When it's done construction, it is pushed to the appropriate `vector<Circle>` or `vector<Square>`, etc, to keep track of the `Shape`'s that are ready for the user to use. (Each `Shape` has an ID, so that I can push it to the appropriate vector.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly about the getters/setters, I felt kind of dirty including them in my code. Although, I think I will need some of my getters will be necessary, as I will need to pull `name`'s and `description`'s to display to the user. 

How would I avoid using getters if I need to access its `private` data-members constantly? I can't declare them publicly with `const` (other than `name` and `description`), as some of the values of the data members will change (based on level, bonuses, etc).

Comment: Just to clear up the whole `ShapeFactory` subject: Each `ShapeFactory` will need to keep track of which derived-from-`Shape` classes it "constructs" (not in the programming sense). So, each `ShapeFactory` would have its own `vector<Shape*> constrQueue`, and its own vectors of `Circle`'s, etc, to keep track of "constructed" and ready-to-use shapes. This is where I would be pushing `Circle` objects to the construction queue (the `vector<Shape*>`), and push them to the `vector<Circle>` when they are constructed.
Is there a smarter way of approaching this?

Comment: Quote: `I will need to pull name's and description's to display to the user`. I think that is a bad idea. Pass an interface to object that does the display then let the object decide what is displayed. `void Shape::display(DisplayInterface& di);`

Comment: `This is where I would be pushing Circle objects to the construction queue (the vector<Shape*>), and push them to the vector<Circle> when they are constructed. Is there a smarter way of approaching this?` Yes. Just keep a vector of shape. It seems unlikely you need to differentiate then later when you don't earlier.

Comment: I don't know why, but your last comment made it sink in that I really do not need to differentiate between the two. I'm not entirely sure what I was thinking, it would suffice to to use a `Shape` vector. Still relatively new to this, forgive me! I've implemented a CRPT, but if I just keep the "constructed" shapes in another base class vector, I wouldn't need the assignment operator, therefore not the CRPT either.

Also, could you provide question/thread that has an example of a simple `DisplayInterface` like you've described?

Eitherway, you are a god-send, thank you for the reply!

Comment: @JhomasTefferson: See extension to answer.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I have a basic DisplayInterface class set up and it's working.

Out of curiousity, I also attempted using the `friend` `operator<<`. I used that template exactly. My `Circle`'s print is:

`void print(std::ostream& stream) { stream << name << " radius: " << radius; }`

Upon compiling, I get an error converting-->"'void Shape::print(std::ostream &)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Shape' to 'Shape &'"

It also seems to complain about the `return stream;` line in the `operator<<` function: "returning address of local variable or temporary"

Any ideas? Sorry hah.

Comment: This is how I'm calling it in the main: 
`Circle c(10);
std::cout << c;`

Comment: Add a const `void print(std::ostream& stream) const` In both Shape and Circle.

Comment: Ooh that helped, thanks. I also just noticed you missed the `&` in `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream stream`, which also solved one of the errors I was getting. (ie, it should be `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ...`)

Comment: I'd like to thank you for everything btw, not many people will stick through that many questions. I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 5):

1. Initialise member variable outside the body of the constructor. e.g.,

   ```
   Shape(string const& name, int edges) : name(name), edges(edges) {}
   Circle(int radius) : Shape("Circle", 1), radius(radius) {}
   ```
2. The `getName` function should return by `const` reference (since it's actually backed by a real value in your class), not by value. That way, the string doesn't have to get copied. (On the other hand, returning by value is appropriate if you're returning a temporary object that isn't backed by anything.)
3. All the getter functions should be declared `const`. e.g.,

   ```
   virtual string const& getName() const;
   virtual int getEdges() const;
   ```
4. Since the `name` and `edges` properties are inherent to `Shape`, the implementation of `getName` and `getEdges` should live there, not in `Circle`. Thus, they should not be pure virtual.
5. Consider creating two overloads for `Circle::operator=`, one that takes a `Shape const&` (and does the `dynamic_cast`) and one that takes `Circle const&`. That way, when it's known at compile-time that you're passing in a `Circle`, you skip the `dynamic_cast`. (Some C++ programmers consider RTTI to be expensive and when you can avoid RTTI easily, like here, it's probably worth doing.)
6. Since you were planning to throw an exception if it weren't a `Circle`, you can use the reference form of `dynamic_cast`. You can catch-and-rethrow (`throw;` with no arguments does a rethrow) if you want to do some logging in between.
7. Why have a separate `assign` function? Your `operator=` is already virtual, you should do all the work in there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've implemented some of these suggestions already! (Daunting with 50ish .cpp and .h files!)

Just a quick question: Should I be returning everything as `const` references? Even `int` returns? ie, `const int& getID();`? Would referencing the smaller data types make a difference? 

Furthermore, should I do this with my `vector`'s? (ie, `const std::vector<Shape>& getShapes()`). Or would it be better to write a copy constructor for `Shape`?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there anything here that jumps out at you as dangerous and/or wrong?

The problem you are trying to solve is the x-y problem. You are trying to treat circles (a specialized class) in a generic matter, without having the public API of Shape reflect that.

The correct solution is to add the operations that apply to the hierarchy to the shape class, not hack them on, down the hierarchy.

Usually, when you need to use dynamic_cast in your code, that's a sign that you're defining or using your class hierarchy wrongly (i.e. the problem is either the API of the class hierarchy not being generic enough, or the way it is used in client code (client code works on shapes when it should work on circles instead); adding a dynamic_cast *fixes/avoids the problem, while at the same time increasing module coupling, reducing modularity and introducing the need for future boilerplate code*).

Conceptually also, assigning a generic shape to a specialized shape *doesn't make sense*.

You could categorize your properties into facets/aspects ("these shapes have an area", "these shapes have a gravitational center", etc) and decide which facet each specialization should support/copy/etc. Then, you could:

- add a generic facet API to Shape's public interface
- support whatever facets you need to introduce in a generic way
- add facet specializations as needed, down the hierarchy (and othogonal to it)
- get rid of the dynamic_cast
- marry, have 2.5 kids and a dog, and live happily ever after

> I was just wondering if this would get me into a trouble longer down the line?

It introduces a (bad) implementation dependency into the entire class hierarchy. Consider that you pass your classes to another developer and she wants to add a specialization to Circle:

```
class ColoredCircle: public Circle
{
public:
    // you are forced to implement this to avoid ColoredCircle slicing
    virtual ColoredCircle& operator=(const Shape& s) {
        if (const ColoredCircle* c = dynamic_cast<const ColoredCircle*>(&s))
            assign(*c);
        else{
            throw omg_exception("!");
        }
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    void assign(const ColoredCircle& cc) {
        Circle::assign(cc);
        this->color = cc.color;
    }

private:
    SomeColorType color;
};
```

This works.

If you have five specializations though, you get lots of duplicated code. More than this, you are now forced to propagate dynamic_cast calls through the entire hierarchy (your one-time use of dynamic_cast is now endemic).

You can ease this by implementing a CRTP implementation for the assignment operator ( see [LokiAstari's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54464/8878) ).

Other observations:

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
std::vector<Circle> circs;
Circle c2(5); //Creates a circle with 5 for the radius.

shapes.push_back(&c2); //Pushing the 5-radius circle into the Shapes* vector
```

Here, you are adding the address of an automatic variable to the vector ( I assume this is just SCCCE client code, but still :) ). The object at that address is invalidated before the vector (it works, but the dependency is not explicit).

Comment: What I wanted to say but done more eloquently,

Comment: I replied to Loki's comment with this to clear up my lgoci: There are X number of `ShapeFactory`. Each `ShapeFactory` will need to keep track of which derived-from-Shape classes it "constructs" (not in the programming sense). So, each ShapeFactory would have its own `vector<Shape*> constrQueue`, and its own vectors of `Circle`'s, etc, to keep track of "constructed" and ready-to-use shapes. This is where I would be pushing `Circle` objects to the construction queue (the `vector<Shape*>`), and push them to the `vector<Circle>` when they are constructed. Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: instead of having vector's for `Circle`'s, and all the different derivations to keep track of construction, I push all the derived shapes into a `vector<Shape*>`, and every turn, I simply cycle through the vector and decrement everything that still has turns remaining for construction. When it's done construction, it is pushed to the appropriate `vector<Circle>` or `vector<Square>`, etc, to keep track of the `Shape`'s that are ready for the user to use.

Comment: I feel like the only solution to accomplish this is to have separate `vector<Circle> circConstr;` and `vector<Square> sqConstr;`, etc, to keep track of all the differing "construction queues". It will render the reason behind my base `Shape` class as useless.

Comment: You say "The object at that address is invalidated before the vector (it works, but the dependency is not explicit)." at the end, could you expand on that? What invalidates it? Why is the dependency not explicit (and for a double-dose of honesty, what makes dependency explicit/implicit? Could you provide a thread/question that explains it?

Comment: EDIT to the above: I realize now that the objects I'm creating will go out of scope and thus be destroyed, invalidating the references as a result. I will switch to creating the objects dynamically.

Comment: Ok, so I've decided to completely get rid of casting the base class back to the derived class. Which will rid my need of separate vectors for `Circle`, etc. This will allow me to rid myself of the assignment operator and the `dynamic_cast`. However, when pushing my derived class to the base class `Shape` vector, extra information (ie, the radius) will get sliced. Would using a `vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>` solve this issue? I will require the use of the extra data members defined in `Circle`.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid slicing by using `vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>`.

Comment: There is also [this alternative](http://bannalia.blogspot.fr/2014/05/fast-polymorphic-collections.html) if you don't need to preserve the objects in a specific order in your collection.